# How to show number over icon?

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome

I use Font-Awesome to show the icon. Now I want to add a number over the icon not beside it. How can I do this?

```
<i class="fa fa-calendar-o text-info">10</i>
```

If do like this, 10 will appear beside the icon. How can it be like hover the icon?

Comment: Please take your time and explain clearly.. and also post relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like zimorok answer, try this http://jsfiddle.net/Lm8vdg8u/2/

```
<div id="calendar">
  <span class="day">10</span>
  <i class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-3x text-info"></i>
</div>
```

the CSS

```
#calendar .day{
position: absolute;
z-index: -9999;
top: 30px;
left: 21px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create another div stacking over the icon with z-index value higher than the icon

```
<div class="box">
 <span class="high-z-index">10</span>
 <i class="fa fa-calendar-o text-info"></i>
</div>
```

perhaps you can do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Create Span and hold counter and icon in it.this css even in mobile mode work correctly

```
 .Notification{
          color:white;
          margin-right:30px;
              
      }

      .BellIcon
      {
          font-size:18pt;
      }

      .CounterNotification
      {
          color:red;
          margin-right:-22px;
          font-size:9pt;
          font-weight:bold;
          position:sticky
          
      }

          <span class="Notification">
              <span class="CounterNotification">
                  10
              </span>
              <span class="fa fa-bell fa-lg BellIcon">

              </span>
          </span>
```